# Mysql Ranking based on Category and Branch

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a hard time figuring out and trying how to fix this. 
Can you help me give a logic or idea how can get the ranking of each category for each branch based on sales?

[image]

[image]

For example:

- Rank 1 for branch_code_id = 9 is Accicular since it has 300,000 sales
- Rank 2 for branch_code_id = 9 is WLO since it has only 200,000
  sales.

Same as with other branches. I only need the rank of category for each `branch_code_id`.

I can't figure out how to loop this one. Rank will be placed in the "r" column as you can see in the excel output.

By the way, here's the sql statement i used to get the result you see in the screenshot.

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.date, 
    a.branch_code_id, 
    SUM(b.amount), 
    c.category 
FROM 
    sales_add_h AS a 
    INNER JOIN sales_add_i AS b ON a.id = b.sales_h_id 
    INNER JOIN control_panel_item_create AS c ON b.item_code_id = c.id 
GROUP BY c.category, a.branch_code_id, b.amount 
ORDER BY SUM(b.amount) DESC
```

Thanks Guys!

Comment: can you provide sample database of your scenario

Comment: I uploaded the excel file. (Expected output.)

Comment: Why do you group by `b.amount`, if you `SUM` it?

Comment: why is branchcode_id no. 10 not in rank no.2 since it have 40000 sales?

Comment: @Yassi i meant  to say that can you provide a demo database like on http://sqlfiddle.com/ so there we can go through the scenario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
  @rn:=if(@prv=branch_code_id, @rn+1, 1) as rId, 
  @prv:= branch_code_id as branch_code_id,
  val,
  id, 
  date, 
  category 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.date, 
    a.branch_code_id, 
    SUM(b.amount) as val, 
    c.category 
  FROM 
    sales_add_h AS a 
  INNER JOIN 
    sales_add_i AS b ON a.id = b.sales_h_id 
  INNER JOIN 
    control_panel_item_create AS c ON b.item_code_id = c.id 
  GROUP BY 
    c.category, a.branch_code_id, b.amount 
  ORDER BY 
    a.branch_code_id, SUM(b.amount) DESC)tmp
  JOIN 
    (SELECT @rn:=0, @prv:=0)t
```

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74be9/3)** to understand how ranking works.

I have done ranking for each branch_id as you have mentioned, if you want to rank for each category in a particular branch than you need to add another variable which stores the category and compare it within the `if clause` and also need to sort data within inner query accordingly `order by c.category, a.branch_code_id, SUM(b.amount) DESC`

Comment: Hey this works perfectly :) thank you so much! My last concern is that when I add the WHERE a.branch_code_id = 11 AND c.category = "WLO" it sets the rank = 1 where the rank should be 2.

Comment: When you add where condition, it will filter all the records with the given condition and rank only filtered records. Check the record which you are expecting as rank 1 satisfy condition given in the where clause..

Comment: Thank you Sir! What I did is make a loop and get all rank 1 all the way down from a specific branch. Your code helped me a lot and made my day :) Thank you so much